# Where do we find the Existing Siebel Licenses? Any path that they will be stored?

Tags: siebel

Please let me know where to find any license that is installed in the siebel environments. Where do we find the existing siebel licenses? is there any path for that matter where the details of the licenses are stored?

thanks
Nithish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no apparent programming question.

Comment: Although I do think the poster could have provided a bit more context surrounding his/her question, I do think it's a valid question. Programming should not be the only requirement for a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

Siebel License keys are stored inside the SIEBEL.S_APP_KEY table of the Siebel database. See the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/AppsAdmin/AppsAdminGetStarted4.html) for more details.

Please be aware that these records should not be inserted directly, but via the appropriate admin views inside Siebel itself.